# Возможность печати каждой строки в datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable

Возможно ли сделать чтобы в каждой строке в последней колонки была кнопочка **Печать** при нажатии на которую открывалось бы окно печати конкретно этой строки?

Как печатать всю таблицу я нашел, а вот конкретно строку - не могу справиться.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Возможно, вот только без примера кода подсказать невозможно)

Comment: я нашел решение как печатать только выбранные  - https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36740/print-only-selected-rows-if-there-is-selected-row-otherwise-all-of-them но не могу понять как добавить кнопку печати в каждую строку последней колонки